# Objective-C: naming practice for blocks used as sub-functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, naming-conventions, objective-c-blocks

I want to determine the best current naming practice for a blocks use as a sub-functions.

Unfortunately I'm dealing with some code where blocks are being put inside of methods because objective-c does not have sub-functions.

Is there currently a naming practice for these?

```
 - (void) foo {
    int k=100;

    int (^badIdeaFunc)(int) = ^(int a) { return a+k; };

    NSLog(@"%d", badIdeaFunc (5));

 }
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to use closures as replacement for local methods. So there cannot be a convention.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - Why is it a bad idea? Obj-C does not have local functions *per se* (unlike, say, Swift), but how does a compiler handle a local function which references its enclosing environment? It builds a closure (which is just a code pointer and environment) or something similar (e.g. lookup how Pascal used to be compiled).

Comment: @STLDeveloper *et al*: Voted to reopen; "Is there currently a naming practice for these?" is a question of *existence* not *opinion*. The OP wishes to "determine the best current naming practice" and to do that requests data to inform their decision. The OP does also express an opinion, "Unfortunately...", and some may disagree with it, e.g. why not "I'm dealing with some code where blocks are being put inside of methods because *unfortunately* objective-c does not have sub-functions.", but expressing such an opinion does not make the requested factual data an opinion.

Comment: I agree with Amin, because I'd like to see subfunctions added to ObjC and blocks have unwanted overhead, but I'm dealing with people who refuse to stop using blocks this way.

Comment: @superbus - What is the "unwanted overhead"? Under the hood a "sub function" and a "block" might be compiled in exactly the same way - both require a code pointer and (optionally) some environment information. At the source level a nested function might look nicer than a block, but that is syntactic sugar. But we're off-topic for your original question! ;-)

Comment: @CRD The compiler does not build a closure when building a (local) function. A closure is the "fusion" of code and a creational state. A function does not have such state. Local functions are ordinary functions which nothing else than a different scope. There is no local extent. They do not have an extent at all. Closures have (because of its state). Closures and functions are completely different things.

Comment: Moreover, even he says function, his code shows a method. His example is  about a function inside a method. (And not a function inside a function.) Methods do have a additional state, too, not a creational state, but a object state. In Objective-C (in contrast to Swift) there are no calls, because you send messages which are polymorphic related to methods. (In Swift you only have this for inheritance.) So messages (names) and methods (code) are in a complex relation ship, which is resolved at runtime. Closures do not know that mechanism. They even don't have a name.

Comment: He is not asking for a naming convention of a closure. He is asking for the naming convention for a reference to a closure … If you want to group the scope of a bunch of methods, use categories in Objective-C. You do not need to replace compile-time functions with runtime closures. And so on and so on. To sum up: 1. Closures aren't produced by the compiler, but at runtime. 2. Closures are called via a reference variable, methods are dispatched. 3. Closures do not have names. Names of methods are central for dispatching.

Comment: And now to something completely different: You are right, that the Q is not opinion-based. I vote for reopen.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - While some languages may disallow nested functions from accessing variables in their enclosing scope many do not, for example try defining a nested function in Swift and you will find it has access to variables in the enclosing function. Such access requires more than a simple code pointer, it requires an access/static link in the stack frame or a closure (which bundles the static link or environment together with the code pointer). Whichever method is used involves some cost and it is the compiler which produces the code to maintain the static links or build the closures.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - The OP refers to "subfunctions", so this is nothing to do with method/function differences. Finally it is the naming of variables of block type that sought, that block types are reference types is not relevant. Anyway, all this is off topic for the original question, however interesting it might all be ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no standard convention.

Comment: Is there any Apple source code example of this type of block usage?

Comment: I'm sure it appears somewhere in Apple's sample code, but there's definitely no sample code of this explicitly. It's nothing special. It really is like naming any other variable or function — use a descriptive name, and generally camelCaseNaming is preferred style as it always is in C-based languages.

Comment: @CRD Pardon, I did miss that when the answer came up when reviewing. I'll delete my remark.

Comment: @CRD No evidence seth did a search.

Comment: @superbus - Well there is as much "evidence" that seth did a search as there is for the "OP" having done one... Of course seth might just happen to be familiar with the naming conventions and know there is not one for local variables which happen to be of block type, and so didn't need to "search". I think the original question was reasonable and putting it on hold unjustified, but I'm beginning to wonder... Hopefully the OP will just give seth a tick.

Comment: @superbus FYI, I've been writing Obj-C for 15 years.